# When Creating Data Frame Character Values Are Stripped From Alphanumeric String

Tags: r

When creating a dataframe one of the columns is alpanumeric and the alpha characters are stripped on

```
>View(df)
```

Code for data frame:

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(df[,1],df[,2],df[,3],df[,4],df[,5],
                          df[,6],df[,7],df[,8],df[,9]))
```

Column 5 is the field. Example values:

```
YC1275421
YW3759841
YC1289724
```

When viewing the dataframe the values are:

```
1275421
3759841
1289724
```

I also exported the dataframe and confirmed that the alpha characters were stripped.

How do I create the dataframe so that it contains the alphanumeric string?

Comment: `df <- df[1:9]` is what you should have done. and also make your example reproducible

Comment: This will be difficult to help with unless we have a reproducible example. However, as rawr alluded to `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` is typically a good sign that something unexpected and unwanted is going to happen.

Comment: I cannot recreate this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see this problem, try this solution.

```
df <- data.frame(df[,1],df[,2],df[,3],df[,4],df[,5],
                          df[,6],df[,7],df[,8],df[,9])
```

or give head of the data so I can come with better solution.

Comment: Yes, that fixed the issue Sangram. Thank you! I'll be sure to provide the head data should I run into anymore problems.